# Splat: Locator.Current vs Locator.CurrentMutable

Tags: reactiveui, splat

So, Splat provides two ways to retrieve a service:

```
var s1 = Locator.Current.GetService<IMyService>();
var s2 = Locator.CurrentMutable.GetService<IMyService>();
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/reactiveui/splat#service-location) is unclear about which way we should use.

So what is the difference between these two? Which one should we use? Which one should we avoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Locator.Current** is ReadOnly version, should be used unless you are registering services.
**Locator.CurrentMutable** is read/write version, should only be used when registering services.

They both point towards the same locators, just based on use cases which variable you use.

Basically:

- use CurrentMutable to register services,
- use Current whenever you need to retrieve them.

Comment: Sooooo... Should I use Locator.CurrentMutable *only* during registration and Locator.Current any other time? Is this the right approach?